# Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making an app for IoT Devices. The activity starts receiving data on button click. But I'm getting this error.

W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

```
        // Read from the database
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.

                    if(StringValue.length()>0 && link2.length()>0) {

                        try {
                        status = dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog").getValue().toString();}
                        catch (NullPointerException ignored){}

                        if(status==null){
                            TextView text4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                            text4.setText(" Error: Wrong ID. ");
                            // Toast...
                            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 540);
                            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setView(layout);
                            toast.show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);

                            pin.setText(status);

                            final int value = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
                            if (analogvalue > value) {
                                Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1");
                                fireChild.setValue(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                Firebase fireChild1 = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2");
                                fireChild1.setValue(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());

                            }
                            if (analogvalue <= value) {
                                if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                                if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LOW")) {Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                                if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                                if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LOW")) {Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.banaao.makersplace.iotsense, PackageName:com.banaao.makersplace.iotsense
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132932(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 21(744KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 35MB/40MB, paused 1.556ms total 109.059ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 94569(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 38MB/40MB, paused 8.078ms total 68.990ms

Comment: have you found the solution when i run app it  called two time i dont know and after run it show me a message when i click any widget that is removeinvalide node . have you any idea about it